# Running "Imp" commands in Oracle 19c

Tags: oracle, database-backups

We've recently switched to using the Oracle 19c client, but I have some old scripts that used to run the following with an Oracle 11/12 client:

> imp dbname/password@%DB_VAR% fromuser=user1 touser=user1 tables=(table_1,table_1_x) file=tables_1.dmp ignore=y

However, it looks like imp is now deprecated as I'm getting the usual

> 'imp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

I can't find imp.exe anywhere to add to the path either.

Is there a simple replacement / missing component for this or do I need to re-install the oracle 11 client? Struggling to find anything in the documentation.

Comment: The replacement is DataPump (impdp). This is a different file format, so you need to adjust your file production to use the corresponding expdp. Also, while the job can be started from a client, the dump files (for export or import) must be located on (or visible to) the actual database server and accessible using a DIRECTORY object. You cannot export or import files from network locations.

Answer (score 0):

> We've recently switched to using the Oracle 19c **client** ...
>
> ```
> 'imp' is not recognized as an internal or external command
> ```

I think you got it wrong. The `imp` utility is still here, it is now called the [Original Import utility](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-original-import-utility.html).

If you installed Oracle 19c **database** (as opposed to what you said: 19c **client**), you'd have it installed and operational. With a client, it is a different story. It depends on *which* client you installed. There are different "versions" and not all of them contain *everything* (i.e. all utilities, such as SQL*Loader, the original EXP and IMP utilities, etc.).

Have a look at the following document: [Instant Client for SQL*Loader, Export, and Import](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/instant-client-sql-loader-export-import.html#GUID-FF1B6F75-09F5-4911-9317-9776FAD15965).

---

Therefore, from my point of view, it is not that `imp` (you tried to run) doesn't exist - it is just that you didn't **install** it.